# Redirect folder access to file (but not redirect files in folder)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have a webpage set up at `abc.com/folder/` and there are multiple .php files in this folder that need to be accessed. Because of conflicts between a smooth scroll script and my shared navigation files, I am looking for a .htaccess rule that will redirect `abc.com/folder/` to `abc.com/folder/index.php`, but will not redirect `abc.com/folder/xyz.php`. Currently I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?folder/ ^/folder/index.php [R=301,L]
```

but this <s>redirects all files to `index.php`, while I just want the base directory redirected but none of its files.</s> does not change anything.

Edit: Currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?folder/ ^/folder/index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your server is setup but most LAMP servers would assume requests to `abc.com/folder/`  were meant for  `abc.com/folder/index.php`

Comment: It does load the correct page, but my problem is that when I am in `/folder/` and I try to go to `/folder/index.php#about` for example, it has to reload the page and so my smooth scroll script doesn't work. I want a hard redirect from `/folder/` to `/folder.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/?$ /folder/index.php
```

This will redirect to `/folder/index.php` when URI is `/folder/`

Comment: I am looking for a hard redirect though, it loads the content of `/folder/index.php` but when I access `/folder/index.php#about` it still to reload the page the first time because it sees it as a new file.

Comment: But `/folder/index.php#about` and `/folder/index.php` will both behave same because webserver won't even know about `#about`

Comment: But your rule still leaves it as `/folder/` for me, it does not hard redirect to `/folder/index.php`

Comment: You can add a rule like this: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/?$  /folder/index.php` to get a hard redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The following conditions will tell Apache to not rewrite when the requested file exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This is useful if you have other types of rewrite rules, or you send everything to a single file.

Comment: My problem now it that the rules behave like they are not even there (even without your edit, I think my original posting was wrong). I need a hard redirect from `/folder/` to `/folder/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, but how about

RewriteRule ^/?tradeshow/$ ^/tradeshow/index.php [R=301,L]